# Sorting an ArrayList of Strings into alphabetical order after the 11th user input in Java

Tags: java

I have an assignment for school in which I have to have a user enter names which are then put into title case and then alphabetical order. My problem is that if a user enters 11 names or more they no longer become alphabetized. If someone could explain why this is happening and maybe give me some tips to fix this I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    ArrayList <String> names = new ArrayList <String>();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println ("Please Enter a Name. (Enter 'stop' to end)");
    String g = scan.nextLine();
    g = titleCase(g);
    names.add(g);

    while (!g.equals("Stop"))
    {
        System.out.println ("Please Enter a Name. (Enter 'stop' to end)");
        g = scan.nextLine();
        g = titleCase(g);
        if (!g.equals("Stop"))
          abcSort(g, names);
    }

    toString(names);
  }
```

This method is what returns the string into title case.

```
  public static String titleCase(String s)
  {
    String firstLetter;
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    firstLetter = s.substring(0, 1);
    s = firstLetter.toUpperCase() + s.substring(1, s.length());

    return s;
  }
```

This is my method for putting the names into alphabetical order.

```
  public static void abcSort(String inputName, ArrayList <String> sorted)
  {
    String g;
    for (int i = 0; i < sorted.size(); i++)
    {
        g = sorted.get(i); 

        if (inputName.compareTo(g) < 0)
        {
            sorted.add (i, inputName);
            return;
        }
        else {
            sorted.add(inputName);
            return;
        }
    }
  }
```

The assignment requires me to also have a method to print the ArrayList which is what this one does

```
  public static void toString(ArrayList s)
  {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sidebar comment: you're not storing the names after the first time you ask. You need a `names.add(g);` inside your `while` loop.

Comment: The problem is in the `abcSort(...)` method. This method can really only do one of two things: a) either add the new string to the beginning of the list, or b) add the new string to the end of the list.  If you can work out why this happens, you should be able to work out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `abcSort` method. Since you `return` in both the `if` and the `else` part, it's impossible for the `for` loop to get beyond the first string. You want to add the string to the end of this list if it can't go before *any* of the other strings. At the moment it goes to the end if it can't go before the first string. You need to get rid of the `else` and move the line `sorted.add(inputName);` to be after the `for` loop.

A corrected version is:

```
public static void abcSort(String inputName, ArrayList <String> sorted)
{
    String g;
    for (int i = 0; i < sorted.size(); i++)
    {
        g = sorted.get(i);

        if (inputName.compareTo(g) < 0)
        {
            sorted.add (i, inputName);
            return;
        }
    }
    sorted.add(inputName);
}
```

A good IDE can find problems like this. When I paste your version into IntelliJ IDEA, the `for` loop goes a horrible shade of brown and it tells me the problem: `'for' statement does not loop`.

I don't know where you are getting the number 11 from. The original version fails if you enter `Anne, Chris, Bob, Stop`.

Comment: I got 11 from the code runner we enter the homework in to check. Thank you so much for the help! Could you explain what an IDE is though?

Comment: An IDE is a program that you use to write and run programs. I recommend IntelliJ IDEA. You don't need to use an IDE at all but they're useful for finding bugs.